# Subfigures are right aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

If I use subfigures to align two images side-by-side, these are right aligned. I tried several things but doesn't change anything. My current markup looks like this:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}

...

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\null\hfill
\subfigure[Lego Mindstorms Color Sensor 1]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\hfill
\subfigure[Lego Mindstorms Color Sensor 2]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\hfill\null
\rule{35em}{0.5pt}
\caption{Color / RGB Sensors}
\label{img:colorSensor}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you add `\null\fill` to `\centering`?

Comment: ,@dannyyy  - Yes, remove that `\null\hfill` before `\centering` as Bernard's hint.

Comment: You also need to replace the \hfill between the subfigures with \hfil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aim is to equalize the spaces, then `\null\hfill` is not the right way. Note that `\null` does not start horizontal mode (that is, a paragraph), so all it does is to create some vertical space.

Note also that `subfigure` has been obsolete and deprecated for 15 years.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\hspace*{\fill}%
\subfloat[Lego Mindstorms Color Sensor 1]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Lego Mindstorms Color Sensor 2]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}%
\hspace*{\fill}

\caption{Color / RGB Sensors}
\label{img:colorSensor}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfigure[Lego Mindstorms Color Sensor 1]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\hspace{2em}
\subfigure[Lego Mindstorms Color Sensor 2]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\rule{35em}{0.5pt}
\caption{Color / RGB Sensors}
\label{img:colorSensor}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: subfigure]